# Azure DevOps - Use parameter to set path trigger in yaml pipeline definition

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'd like to set up an Azure pipeline using yaml template. What I struggle with is the path triggers definition. I'd like the individual pipelines to start up, only if they actually differ from their earlier versions.

`core.yaml` is a generic template, which is used across the different projects.

```
parameters:
- name: projectPath
  type: string

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - feature/*
  paths:
    include: 
    - ${{ parameters.projectPath }} # this is the problematic part

steps:
  ... # restore, build, test, etc tasks are defined here
```

`build.yaml` files are defined for every project. They only extend on `core.yaml` and supply the
required parameters:

```
extends:
  template: core.yaml
  parameters:
    projectPath: src/project1
```

Using the value `${{ parameters.projectPath }}` fails as "Template expression is not allowed in the given context". Same occurs if I surround it with quotes.

Using the value `$(parameters.projectPath)` works, but it triggers even if I change a file outside the defined path.

I also tried using the actual values instead of a parameter (e.g. "src/project1"), but it also triggers for every change, even if I only touch the file "src/project2/foo.md".

The examples I saw did not use triggers within a template. But normally I got a syntax error when the pipeline is triggered (e.g. unexpected value) when I misplaced a node. So it's just my expectation that it should work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like it's being pretty clear with you – you can't use a template expression in that context.
I suppose you'll need to put the triggers in each separate pipeline, instead of in the template.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Correct, that was my conclusion as well, but I hoped I just overlooked something. Because this way I'd need to copy + paste the "trigger' block in a bunch of yaml files rather than just adding it to the template.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because this part

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - feature/*
  paths:
    include: 
    - ${{ parameters.projectPath }} # this is the problematic part
```

needs to be known on compilation time, but you provide parameter which is evaluated at runtime.

And this syntax `$(parameters.projectPath)` doesn't make any sense, and probably is evaluated to empy value and then everything is included into trigger.

Comment: I tried using the actual value (and not a parameter) but it still didn't work.